# How to access virtual dediacated server through the static IP

Tags: dedicated

I have purchased virtual dedicated server 2008. How to access some files stored on the server through the static ip address given to us?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install a server program on the server that serves the static files you've got stored there. Usually for files that means either a HTTP server or FTP server.

I use FileZilla on our servers for FTP, and it works nicely.

Comment: well thats a good idea but cant we access the shared folder directly like we do incase of LAN?